# Deploy on weblogic fail

Tags: oracle, weblogic, weblogic12c

When i tried deploy an application on weblogic, im stand with this exception:

```
No EJBs found in the ejb-jar file 'myproject-core.jar'. Please ensure the ejb-jar contains EJB declarations via an ejb-jar.xml deployment descriptor or at least one class annotated with the @Stateless, @Stateful, @Singleton or @MessageDriven EJB annotation.
```

In my ejb-jar.xml i have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd"
    version="3.1">

</ejb-jar>
```

maybe this is a miss configuration, or an fail in build proccess, i dont have ideia what can i solve this.

Comment: it's clear that you don't have any ejb declared in your xml, so do you have any ejb with annotations ? ( `@Stateless, @Stateful, @Singleton or @MessageDriven` EJB annotation)

Comment: yes, i have annotations, how can i declare it in my project ?

Comment: actually im migrating jboss to weblogic, in jboss the app run normally

Comment: maybe there is a jboss-ejb3.xml in your project ? (or some proprietary jboss xml descriptor that needs to be migrated)

Comment: I just have an ejb-jax.xml, and have this: 

<ejb-jar xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_1.xsd"
 version="3.1">

</ejb-jar>

Comment: Have you setup your weblogic-ejb-jar.xml and your weblogic-cmp-rdbms-jar.xml ?

Comment: Refer to : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24973/ejb_jar_ref.htm#EJBPG488